# Как выгрузить данные из БД?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Добавляю данные в БД:

```
 try:
        connection = MySQLConnection.connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mydb.categories (CatName) VALUES ('{CatName}')".format(CatName=CatName))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

Читаю данные из БД:

```
 try:
        connection = MySQLConnection.connection()
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT CatName FROM mydb.categories")
            List = cursor.fetchall()
            row = cursor.rowcount
            connection.close()
            print(List)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

Это все отдельные функции.

Когда вызываю функцию вывода `Select`, то получаю вывод такого вида:

```
    Доступные категории товаров:
[('Food',), ('Cars',), ('Animals',)]
```

Подскажите, где тут ошибка, как вывести категории без лишних символов?

Дальше с этим списком хочу делать сравнение с вводом пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `cursor.fetchall()` всегда возвращает список кортежей. Даже если в `SELECT` выбирается всего один столбец `cursor.fetchall()` вернет список кортежей, состоящих из единственного элемента - как в примере из вашего вопроса.

Попробуйте так:

```
categories = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    categories.append(row[0])
```

Comment: спасибо. Но сработал только второй вариант почему то.
categories = []
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                categories.append(row[0])
Вывод стал такой: ['Food', 'Cars', 'Animals']

Comment: @Mik Как вариант, можете попробовать короткую запись `categories = [ row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall() ]`

Comment: @MaxU Можетеподсказать, почему дальше, у меня не сравнивается ввод в этом листе?
    CatName = str(input())
    for i in str(ListCategory())1:
        if CatName != i:
            print("Такой категории нет")
        else:

Comment: @Mik, советую открыть  новый SO вопрос и привести в нем небольшой пример данных и ожидаемый результат...