# Как правильно организовать условие в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

В [прошлой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1292470/python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-mysql/1292473?noredirect=1#comment2278262_1292473):

```
try:
    connection = MySQLConnection.connection()
    if connection.is_connected():
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT CatName FROM mydb.categories")
        List = cursor.fetchall()
        row = cursor.rowcount
        connection.close()
        print(List)
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Мне подсказали как сделать правильный вывод списка:

```
['Food', 'Cars', 'Animals']
```

Далее, хочу чтобы при вводе значения оно сравнивалось с этим списком. Но в данном коде не пойму почему он не работает:

```
ListCategory()
    CatName = str(input())
    
    if CatName in str(ListCategory()):
        print("Такой категории нет")
    else:
        print("Введите стоимость:")
        Price = int(input())
        print("Введите дату покупки: гггг-мм-дд")
        iDate = str(input())
        Date = DT.datetime.strptime(iDate, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Как правильно сравнить значение, чтобы если оно совпадает, то код идет дальше, если нет - то ввод повторно?

Comment: Не понимаю, что это? Создаете класс ListCategory? Этот код не будет работать в питоне. Плюс переменные принято называть в стиле snake_case. У вас как попало.

Или ListCategory это список с такого рода данными: ['Food', 'Cars', 'Animals']?

Comment: Что делает эта строчка - ListCategory() ? PS. Нет нужды переводить результат ввода в строку, потому что он уже строка. str(input()) - лишнее, просто input() достаточно

Comment: @Эникейщик Добавил код функции ListCategory()

Comment: @Alpensin Добавил код функции ListCategory()

Comment: А в строке ``if CatName in str(ListCategory())`` вы проверяете наличие CatName в... где?

Comment: @Эникейщик в списке ['Food', 'Cars', 'Animals'] который должна возвращать ListCategory()

Comment: ListCategory() ничего  у вас не возвращает. (Ок, возвращает None, но это потому что питон так устроен)

Comment: ListCategory() вызывая эту функцию в консоли выводится список... Ну а как тогда правильно сделать?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT CatName FROM mydb.categories")
categories = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
CatName = input()

if CatName.capitalize() in categories:
    ...
```